# Mouse Move Too Fast To Check Collision

Tags: java, performance, mouse, drag, collision

I'm having a problem with a sliding block game as when I try to ram two blocks at a fast speed, the collision code messes up. It works if the mouse speed is slower though. Is there a way to put a maximum cap on the mouse speed or to change my code so it doesn't happen?

```
    //when the mouse is dragged and component selected is not null, continue
    if (componentName != null) {
        //get the current mouse x and y assuming that it was clicked from the middle of the component
        mouseX = e.getX() - carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getWidth() / 2;
        mouseY = e.getY() - carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getHeight() / 2;
        //get the direction of the selected component
        direction = group.get(mapsIndex)[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].updown(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(componentName)));
        //if the direction is horizontal, make sure that the object is not dragged off the screen (right and left)
        if (direction == true) {
            if (mouseX < 50) {
                mouseX = 50;
            } else if (mouseX > 50 * 7 - carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getWidth()) {
                mouseX = 50 * 7 - carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getWidth();
            }
            //get the location of the mouse for the y axis
            mouseY = carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getY();
            //if the direction is vertical, make sure that the object is not dragged off the top and bottom of the screen
        } else {
            if (mouseY < 50) {
                mouseY = 50;
            } else if (mouseY > 50 * 7 - carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getHeight()) {
                mouseY = 50 * 7 - carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getHeight();
            }
            //get the location of the mouse for the x axis
            mouseX = carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getX();
        }
        //find the area that the selected object occupies
        Rectangle or = carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getBounds();
        //go through all other components
        for (int x = 0; x < max; x++) {
            //as long as the comparison is not made with itself or a nonexistant object, continue
            if (x != Integer.parseInt(componentName) && carImage[x] != null) {
                //get the area that the compared object occupies
                Rectangle collide = carImage[x].getBounds();
                //if the two areas intersect, make the selected car go back to where it was
                if (or.intersects(collide)) {
                    mouseX = carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getX();
                    mouseY = carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].getY();
                }
            }
        }

        //update the component's location to where the mouse is
        carImage[Integer.parseInt(componentName)].setLocation(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use more-efficient collision detection, such as [a quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Comment: When sampling the mouse, and it goes from (x,y) to (u,v) in - say - less than 1/3 second, just "draw" the line in between, ie analyze all points on this line. The formula is basic mathematics.

Comment: @MattBall: how would you implement a quadtree for collision in this case? Sorry I'm not very advanced at programming...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go on the path where you try to limit mouse speed - users have individual preferences.

What you can do is to divide user interaction from system behavior to increase reliability. Hold and update the current position and calculate collision in the background thread at specified intervals - if collision occurs, move the user back. You should be able to run it at shorter intervals than noticeable by the user. And you can increase performance by utilizing more cores, i.e. Java 7 ForkJoin pool is a simple solution.